# JQ, convert CSV (parent child format) to JSON

Tags: json, csv, parent-child, jq

I have a CSV file (parent child format). Is it possible to convert to JSON format by using JQ ?

**CSV file**
`<pre>`

```
id  parent_id   text
1   NULL        engine
2   1           exhaust
3   1           cooling
4   3           cooling fan
5   3           water pump
6   NULL        frame
7   6           wheels
8   6           brakes
9   8           brake calipers
10  6           cables
</Pre>
```

**JSON file**
`<Pre>`

```
[
{
"id": "1",
"text": "engine",
"children": [
{
"id": "2",
"text": "exhaust",
"children": []
},
{
"id": "3",
"text": "cooling",
"children": [
{
"id": "4",
"text": "cooling fan",
"children": []
},
{
"id": "5",
"text": "water pump",
"children": []
}
]
}
]
},
{
"id": "6",
"text": "frame",
"children": [
{
"id": "7",
"text": "wheels",
"children": []
},
{
"id": "8",
"text": "brakes",
"children": [
{
"id": "9",
"text": "brake calipers",
"children": []
}
]
},
{
"id": "10",
"text": "cables",
"children": []
}
]
}
]
</Pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following provides the basis for a complete solution to the stated problem.  Instead of
providing the redundant details about the children, it just provides their ids.  If you really need the redundancy, then simply add one more post-processing step, which is trivial to do.

The solution here is based on the construction of a dictionary of "children".

#### Invocation

Along the lines of:

```
jq -R -f program.jq data.csv
```

#### Program

```
def obj($headers):
  . as $in
  | reduce range(0; $headers|length) as $i ({}; 
      .[$headers[$i]] = $in[$i]);

split(",") as $headers
| [ inputs
    | split(",")
    | map_values(if . == "NULL" then null else . end)
    | obj($headers) ]
| (reduce .[] as $row ({};
      if $row.parent_id
      then .[$row.parent_id] += [$row.id]
      else . end ) ) as $children
| map( del(.parent_id) | .children = ($children[.id] // []) )
```

### Output

With the given input, the output begins as follows:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "text": "engine",
    "children": [
      "2",
      "3"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "text": "exhaust",
    "children": []
  },
```

Comment: Hi, Peak, many thanks for a very quick answer. I created two files and then run jq-win64.exe -R 1208.jq 1208.csv, it gives me jq: error: syntax error, unexpected IDENT, expecting $end (Windows cmd shell quo
ting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
1208.jq
jq: 1 compile error   and I run jq-win64.exe -R -s -f 1208.jq 1208.csv, it gives me []. I did something wrong ? Another question:  if ID is text, will it work ? I am new to JQ. Sorry for such questions.

Comment: Please see the update regarding invocation.  The `id` is assumed to be text since that's what your JSON indicates.  If it's not text, then the given solution would need to be tweaked.

Comment: I have some other questions, I can only post as a new question. So I did it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65278602/jq-convert-csv-parent-child-format-to-json-another-questions